# Maximum hourglass sum possible in a 6*6 array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

There is a question on 2D array which says

Given a 6*6 matrix we have to print the largest (maximum) hourglass sum found in the matrix.
An hourglass is described as:

```
a b c
  d
e f g
```

Sample Input

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 2 4 4 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 1 2 4 0
```

Sample Output

```
19
```

Explanation

The sample matrix contains the following hourglasses:

```
1 1 1   1 1 0   1 0 0   0 0 0
  1       0       0       0
1 1 1   1 1 0   1 0 0   0 0 0

0 1 0   1 0 0   0 0 0   0 0 0
  1       1       0       0
0 0 2   0 2 4   2 4 4   4 4 0

1 1 1   1 1 0   1 0 0   0 0 0
  0       2       4       4
0 0 0   0 0 2   0 2 0   2 0 0

0 0 2   0 2 4   2 4 4   4 4 0
  0       0       2       0
0 0 1   0 1 2   1 2 4   2 4 0
```

The hourglass with maximum sum (19) is

```
2 4 4
  2
1 2 4
```

I have written a program where I have made a function for calculating the sum of hourglass. Now I have made a loop that calls this function for every four hourglass possible for a row. And for every four rows that can make a hourglass.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int sum(int a[6][6],int i,int j)
{
    int n=i+3;
    int m=j+3;
    int sum=0;
   for(i;i<n;i++)
   {
       for(j;j<m;j++)
       {
           if(i==n-2)
           {
               sum += a[i][j+1];
               break;
           }
          else
             sum += a[i][j];
       }   
   }
   // printf("%d\t",sum);
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    int arr[6][6];
    int i,j,n,k;
    int max=0;
    for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++){
       for(int arr_j = 0; arr_j < 6; arr_j++){

          scanf("%d",&arr[arr_i][arr_j]);
       }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        k=0;
        while(k<4)
        {
            n=sum(arr,i,k);
          //  printf("%d\t",n);
            k++;
            if(n>max)
                max=n;

        }
    }
    printf("%d",max);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, or is this method not correct for doing this problem?

My program prints `10` as output.

Comment: Please show us some examples of input and expected and actual output.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. While posting code showing what you have tried is great and helps us give a good response, adding an explanation of what the code outputs and how that differs from what you were expecting helps us give the best response that we can. For more information please read the `Describe The Problem` section here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [Maximum sum of hour glass in matrix](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-hour-glass-matrix/)

Comment: regarding: `for(i;i<n;i++)` and `for(j;j<m;j++)`   The first expression is for initialization of the loop.  the single char `i` or `j` is not initialization.  The compiler will complain about those two statements.  to correct use: `for( ;i<n;i++)` and `for( ;j<m;j++)`.   for ease of readability and understanding use a space inside the parens and after the `;`  I.E. `for( ; j<m; j++ )`

Comment: regarding: `int i,j,n,k;` the variables `i` and `j` are not used in the `main()` function.  it is best to not declare variables that are not used.  Your compiler should have told you about this.

Comment: i have done the editing hope it helps  @Jamey

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. -2, 3, 6  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: `for(j;j<m;j++)` : Need reset `j`. Like `int sum=0;` --> `int sum=0, k = j;`, `for(j;j<m;j++)` --> `for(j = k; j < m; j++)`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: this kind of code sequence: `k=0; while(k<4) ... k++`  is much better written as: `for( k=0; k<4: k++ )`

Comment: This worked @BLUEPIXY Can you explain me though why does it need to be reset ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY but this does not work with negative numbers in matrix

Comment: _with negative numbers_ Add to post such case.

Comment: Thanks @user3629249 since i am being new to programming will keep those points in mind while coding next time

Comment: @BLUEPIXY add to post meaning?

Comment: `j` must be returned to the argument value for each outer loop.

Comment: ...because on 2nd and 3rd iterations of outer loop, `j == m` and so already out.

Comment: @Poojasingh  Please add an example of input when it does not work well.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: If there are negative numbers change `int max=0;` to `int max=INT_MIN;` and `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: @WeatherVane that's right. You have sharp eyes.

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, bot).  in the function: `sum()`1) the parameters `i` and `j` are meaningless,  suggest using: `startRow` and `startCol`.   2) the local variables `n` and `m` are meaningless. suggest using: `maxRow` and `maxCol`.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks this works for negative number

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for helping out

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to name a local variable the same as the name of the enclosing function.  Function names should indicate (usually via an active verb) what the function does. Therefore suggest, rename the function: `sum()` to `calculateSum()`

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d",max);`  1) for readability, use spaces inside parens and after the comma. 2) the output will not be displayed until the program exits.  For immediate (preferred) display timing, append a new line to the format string.  I.E. `printf( "%d\n", max );`

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Therefore, should remove the `#include` statements for: `math.h`, `string.h`, `assert.h`, `limits.h`, `stdbool.h`

Answer (score 3):

The error is probably in your `sum` function. The way you did it is a bit of an overkill, it'd be much simpler (and readable!) for you to do sth like this:

```
#define GRID_SIZE (6)
int sum(int a[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE], int i, int j)
{   // Define an hourglass by the index i,j of its central element
    int sum = a[j-1][i-1] + a[j-1][i] + a[j-1][i+1] +
                            a[j][i] +
              a[j+1][i-1] + a[j+1][i] + a[j+1][i+1];
    return sum;
}
```

Then just be sure you iterate with sane values (in [1, len-2]):

```
for (int i = 1; i < (GRID_SIZE-1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < (GRID_SIZE-1); j++)
    {
        n = sum(arr, i, j);
        if (n > max)
            max = n;

    }
}
```

Edit: Check that it works here: http://www.cpp.sh/46jhy

Thanks, that was light fun :-).

PS: Make sure you check some coding standards document, it'll make your life a lot easier in the long run, just search for "C code format standard" and get used to trying to work with one you like. Unless you do something new and on your own, you will probably have to follow a standard and maybe not even have a say in which one, so get familiar with general rules and used to following one, whichever you like.

Comment: You could help ensure that `i` and `j` are in range with assertions: `assert(i > 0 && i < (6-1)); assert(j > 0 && j < (6-1));` — where I'm slightly exercised about whether to write `5` or `(6-1)`; the latter at least hints where the value comes from, whereas `5` on its own might or might not be related to the array dimensions.

Comment: yeah, I thought about that and somehow decided against it, will change the 5 to (6-1) ^^.

Comment: +1 for the visual calculation of the hourglass. Also, if we're talking "style" / good practice, the `6` should probably be something like `#define GRID_SIZE (6)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some overkill — four different ways to write the 'hourglass sum' function.  For reasons outlined in [user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724783/maximum-hourglass-sum-possible-in-a-66-array#comment76433695_44724783), I've renamed the functions to `hourglass_N` (for N in 1..4).  Of these variants, `hourglass_1()` is pretty neat for this particular shape, but `hourglass_2()` is more readily adaptable to other shapes.

The test code correctly handles matrices with negative maximum sums.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { ARR_SIZE = 6 };

static int hourglass_1(int a[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE], int i, int j)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i < ARR_SIZE - 2 && j >= 0 && j < ARR_SIZE - 2);
    int sum = a[i+0][j+0] + a[i+0][j+1] + a[i+0][j+2]
                          + a[i+1][j+1] +
              a[i+2][j+0] + a[i+2][j+1] + a[i+2][j+2];
    return sum;
}

static int hourglass_2(int a[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE], int i, int j)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i < ARR_SIZE - 2 && j >= 0 && j < ARR_SIZE - 2);
    static const int rows[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2 };
    static const int cols[] = { 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2 };
    enum { HG_SIZE = sizeof(rows) / sizeof(rows[0]) };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < HG_SIZE; k++)
        sum += a[rows[k]+i][cols[k]+j];
    return sum;
}

static int hourglass_3(int a[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE], int i, int j)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i < ARR_SIZE - 2 && j >= 0 && j < ARR_SIZE - 2);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 3; i1++)
    {
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < 3; j1++)
        {
            if (i1 == 1)
            {
                sum += a[i + i1][j + j1 + 1];
                break;
            }
            else
                sum += a[i + i1][j + j1];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

static int hourglass_4(int a[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE], int i, int j)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i < ARR_SIZE - 2 && j >= 0 && j < ARR_SIZE - 2);
    int n = i + 3;
    int m = j + 3;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i1 = i; i1 < n; i1++)
    {
        for (int j1 = j; j1 < m; j1++)
        {
            if (i1 == n - 2)
            {
                sum += a[i1][j1 + 1];
                break;
            }
            else
                sum += a[i1][j1];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

typedef int (*HourGlass)(int arr[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE], int i, int j);

static void test_function(int arr[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE], const char *tag, HourGlass function)
{
    int max_sum = 0;
    int max_row = 0;
    int max_col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (ARR_SIZE-2); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (ARR_SIZE-2); j++)
        {
            int n = (*function)(arr, i, j);
            if (n > max_sum || (i == 0 && j == 0))
            {
                max_sum = n;
                max_row = i;
                max_col = j;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s: %3d at (r=%d,c=%d)\n", tag, max_sum, max_row, max_col);
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[ARR_SIZE][ARR_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]) != 1)
            {
               fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read integer (for row %d, col %d)\n", i, j);
               return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    test_function(arr, "hourglass_1", hourglass_1);
    test_function(arr, "hourglass_2", hourglass_2);
    test_function(arr, "hourglass_3", hourglass_3);
    test_function(arr, "hourglass_4", hourglass_4);

    return 0;
}
```

For various different data sets, the code produces the correct answer.

Set 1:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 2 4 4 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 1 2 4 0

hourglass_1:  19 at (r=3,c=2)
hourglass_2:  19 at (r=3,c=2)
hourglass_3:  19 at (r=3,c=2)
hourglass_4:  19 at (r=3,c=2)
```

Set 2:

```
-1 -1 -1 +0 +0 +0
+0 -1 +0 +0 +0 +0
+1 -1 +1 +0 +0 +0
+0 +0 -2 +4 -4 +0
+0 +0 +0 +2 +0 +0
+0 +0 +1 +2 -4 +0

hourglass_1:   7 at (r=2,c=2)
hourglass_2:   7 at (r=2,c=2)
hourglass_3:   7 at (r=2,c=2)
hourglass_4:   7 at (r=2,c=2)
```

Set 3:

```
-7 -2 -9 -7 -4 -4
-6  0 -7 -5 -8 -1
-9 -1 -2 -1 -3 -3
-9 -1 -3 -6 -2 -9
-8 -1 -3 -7 -7 -9
 0 -3 -5 -2 -2 -5

hourglass_1: -18 at (r=2,c=1)
hourglass_2: -18 at (r=2,c=1)
hourglass_3: -18 at (r=2,c=1)
hourglass_4: -18 at (r=2,c=1)
```

Set 4:

```
-7 -7  0 -7 -8 -7
-9 -1 -5 -6 -7 -8
-2  0 -7 -7 -6 -3
-5 -3 -1 -6 -3 -1
-3 -5  0 -5  0 -7
-1 -2 -8 -8 -9 -9

hourglass_1: -20 at (r=2,c=0)
hourglass_2: -20 at (r=2,c=0)
hourglass_3: -20 at (r=2,c=0)
hourglass_4: -20 at (r=2,c=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numbers[6][6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            scanf("%d",&numbers[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int currentHourGlass;
    int largestSum = -999;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++){
            currentHourGlass = 0;
            currentHourGlass += numbers[i-1][j-1];
            currentHourGlass += numbers[i-1][j];
            currentHourGlass += numbers[i-1][j+1];
            currentHourGlass += numbers[i][j];
            currentHourGlass += numbers[i+1][j-1];
            currentHourGlass += numbers[i+1][j];
            currentHourGlass += numbers[i+1][j+1];
            
            if (currentHourGlass > largestSum)
            {
                largestSum = currentHourGlass;
            }

        }
    }

   printf("%d", largestSum);
```

}